# code returns a nullpointerexception when calling jdbc arguments

Tags: java, mysql, nullpointerexception

I am trying to use a method coming from a separate class. The problem is that it returns a nullpointerexception.

The original platform of the project file was JDK 12. After knowing that connect/J is dropped in JDK 8, I converted the platform to JDK 1.7. Still, the predicament occurs.

I use mysql-connector-java-5.1.47 to connect to PHPMyAdmin.

Here are the codes that I used:

the main JFrame class that I called the method:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package MyApps;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

import MyLibs.*;
import MyLibs.CarRegFunc.*;
import MyLibs.DataBaseRequiredFunctions.*;

public class carreg extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form carreg
     */
    public carreg() {
        //initComponents();
        setTitle("Guide Dead");
        crdbrf.createTable(this);
        crdbrf.autoID(this);
        txtbrand.requestFocus();
        crdbrf.tableUpdate(this);
    }

    CRDataBaseRequiredFunctions crdbrf = new CRDataBaseRequiredFunctions();

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Generated Code                        

    private void jTable1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        crdbrf.selectRow(this);

    }                                                                         

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(carreg.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(carreg.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(carreg.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(carreg.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new carreg().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public JTextField getDescr() {
        return descr;
    }

    public JTextField getTxtbrand() {
        return txtbrand;
    }

    public JTextField getTxtmodel() {
        return txtmodel;
    }

    public JTextField getTxtregno() {
        return txtregno;
    }

    public JTextField getTxtrfee() {
        return txtrfee;
    }

    public JComboBox<String> getComavl() {
        return comavl;
    }

    public JTable getJTable1() {
        return jTable1;
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> comavl;
    private javax.swing.JTextField descr;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtbrand;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtmodel;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtregno;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtrfee;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

the connection class:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package MyLibs;

import MyApps.carreg;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author MESIAS
 */
public class DataBaseConnect {
    Connection con;

    public void getConnection(){
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/losrent?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC", "root", "");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(carreg.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(carreg.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

}
```

The class that holds the method to be used:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package MyLibs.DataBaseRequiredFunctions;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

import MyApps.*;
import MyLibs.*;

/**
 *
 * @author MESIAS
 */
public class CRDataBaseRequiredFunctions implements IDataBaseRequiredFunctions{
    Connection con;
    PreparedStatement pst;
    Statement s;
    ResultSet rs;
    DataBaseConnect dbc = new DataBaseConnect();


    public void autoID(carreg cr){
        dbc.getConnection();
        try{
            s = con.createStatement();
            rs = s.executeQuery("select Max(car_no) from carregistration");
            rs.next();
            rs.getString("Max(car_no)");

            if(rs.getString("Max(car_no)") == null){
                cr.getTxtregno().setText("CAR001");
            }else{
                long id = Long.parseLong(rs.getString("Max(car_no)").substring(3,rs.getString("Max(car_no)").length()));
                id++;

                cr.getTxtregno().setText("CAR" + String.format("%03d", id));
            }

        }catch(SQLException se){
            System.out.println(se.getMessage());            
    }    
    }

    public void tableUpdate(carreg cr){
        int c;
        dbc.getConnection();
        try{
            pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from carregistration");
            rs = pst.executeQuery();

            ResultSetMetaData rd = rs.getMetaData();
            c = rd.getColumnCount();
            DefaultTableModel df = (DefaultTableModel)cr.getJTable1().getModel();
            df.setRowCount(0);

            while(rs.next()){
                Vector v2 = new Vector();

                for(int i=1; i<=c; i++){
                    v2.add(rs.getString("car_no"));
                    v2.add(rs.getString("brand"));
                    v2.add(rs.getString("model"));
                    v2.add(rs.getString("rent_fee"));
                    v2.add(rs.getString("available"));
                    v2.add(rs.getString("descript"));
                }

                df.addRow(v2);

            }

        }catch(SQLException se){
            System.out.println(se.getMessage());            
    }
    }

    public void createTable(carreg cr){
        dbc.getConnection();
        try{
            DatabaseMetaData md = con.getMetaData();
            rs = md.getTables(null, null, "carregistration", null);
            if(rs.next() == false){
                s = con.createStatement();  
                String qry ="create table carregistration(id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, car_no varchar(255) NOT NULL, brand varchar(255) NOT NULL, model varchar(255) NOT NULL, rent_fee double(12,2) NOT NULL, available varchar(255) NOT NULL, descript varchar(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id))";       
                s.executeUpdate(qry);
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException se)
        {
            System.out.println(se.getMessage());            
        }    
    }

    public void selectRow(carreg cr){
        DefaultTableModel d1 = (DefaultTableModel)cr.getJTable1().getModel();

        int selectIndex = cr.getJTable1().getSelectedRow();
        cr.getTxtregno().setText(d1.getValueAt(selectIndex, 0).toString());
        cr.getTxtbrand().setText(d1.getValueAt(selectIndex, 1).toString());
        cr.getTxtmodel().setText(d1.getValueAt(selectIndex, 2).toString());
        cr.getTxtrfee().setText(d1.getValueAt(selectIndex, 3).toString());
        cr.getComavl().setSelectedItem(d1.getValueAt(selectIndex, 4).toString());
        cr.getDescr().setText(d1.getValueAt(selectIndex, 5).toString());
    }

}
```

The report after running it states this:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at MyLibs.DataBaseRequiredFunctions.CRDataBaseRequiredFunctions.createTable(CRDataBaseRequiredFunctions.java:85)
    at MyApps.carreg.<init>(carreg.java:31)
    at MyApps.carreg$10.run(carreg.java:329)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

I expect that the program will work but did not and return a nullpointerexception.

UPDATE: as I am browsing the net, it seems to be that the problem is with the DataBaseConnection. It returns null for some reason. Only thing is I still do not know how to remedy this problem.

UPDATE: another few minutes of browsing later, I changed my whole DataBaseConnection class like this:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package MyLibs;

import MyApps.carreg;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author MESIAS
 */
public class DataBaseConnect {
    private static Connection con;

    public static void createConnection(){
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/losrent?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC", "root", "");     
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }    
    }

    public static Connection getConnection(){
        return con;
    }

    public static void closeConnection(){
        if(con!=null){
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                 ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

The message still gives out a nullpointerexception but it pertains to other cause than before:

```
run:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at MyLibs.DataBaseRequiredFunctions.CRDataBaseRequiredFunctions.autoID(CRDataBaseRequiredFunctions.java:40)
    at MyApps.carreg.<init>(carreg.java:32)
    at MyApps.carreg$10.run(carreg.java:329)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Any help is appreciated!

This is now the cause of why AutoID is returning null:

```
cr.getTxtregno().setText("CAR" + String.format("%03d", id));
```

UPDATE: when I quote out the problem, it just continues to go onward. All that is inside the public carreg() is returning nullpointerexception. When I quote it out again, it just continues. Help is appreciated!

UPDATE: It turns out that when I close all the files that I opened with NetBeans, it works. NetBeans always gives out such unique products.

Comment: GetConnection is badly written, it should return the connection object or throw an exception

Comment: @JoakimDanielson how do you do that?

Comment: Note: PHPMyAdmin is a web based database management tool. I’m pretty sure you’re not connecting to it with this code.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen the code was running before when it was all in one jframe. When I split it up like this, it stopped running for some reason.